# Char to Integer coversion in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a Char to Int in my c++ program,followed some of the answers from this site but its still not working .
I have a input file with following data in file ld.txt

```
4
8 2
5 6
8 2
2 3
```

**>./LD < ld.txt**

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int i,k;
    char j;
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        j=fgetc(stdin);
        int l =j - 48;
        if(feof(stdin))
            break;
        nums.push_back(l);
        cout<<nums[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
4 
-38 
8 
-16
2
-38
5
-16
6
-38
8
-16
2
-38
2
-16
3
-38
```

Not sure why i am getting the negative numbers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use abbreviations -- many of them are regional in nature and not understood by the global audience of Stack Overflow. For example, what do "O/p" and "-ve" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative numbers in your output represent characters in your input file that have a value of less than 48. Specifically, space (`' '` or 32) and newline (`'\n'` or 10) are each less than 48.

---

Here are other ways to read in a list of integers from a file:

```
// UNTESTED
int main () {
   int i;
   std::vector<int> results;
   while ( std::cin >> i )
       results.push_back(i);
}
```

or

```
// UNTESTED
int main () {
    std::vector<int> results;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
      std::back_inserter(results));
}
```

or [this](http://ideone.com/3THWuY)

```
// Thanks, WhozCraig
int main () {
    std::vector<int> results((std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)),
        std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to ignore ' ' or '\n' while reading from stdin?

Answer (score 0):

`-38 = 10 - 48` i.e. `-38 = '\n' - '0'`

In C (and C++ as well) you can use character literals as integers.

You can skip invalid chars testing the value read:

```
#include <cctype>

if (isdigit(j)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for

```
int main() {
    vector<int> nums;
    int i,k;
    char j;
    while(cin >> j){
        int l =j - 48;
        nums.push_back(l);
    }
    for(int i =0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

The thing is, cin ignores the white space and new line characters. I've never used fgetsc before, but I'm guessing that it doesn't not ignore the white space/newlines

Comment: You should omit he declaration for `i` and `k`, as they are not being used.